# As $\lambda \to \infty$, $||R_{\lambda}(T)|| \to 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

"Let $T \in B(X,X)$. Prove that $||R_{\lambda}(T)|| \to 0$ as $\lambda \to \infty$."

We have that $R_{\lambda}(T)x=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}(x)$. The problem doesn't specify but the book says that they will always assume $X$ to be Banach unless otherwise stated. Since $T$ is bounded and $Dom T=X$, we know that that $R_{\lambda}(T)$ is defined i.e. $(T-\lambda I)x=y$ has a unique solution $x$.

We want to show that $||R_{\lambda}(T)||=\sup_{||x||=1}||R_{\lambda}(T)x||$ is getting closer and closer to $0$. Since $||x||=0$ iff $x=0$, I suppose we want to show that $R_{\lambda}(T)x$ is getting close to $0$ for all $x$ on the boundary of the unit ball.

I'm having trouble getting beyond what I've mentioned above.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Since $||\lambda x||=||(\lambda x-Tx) + Tx|| \leq ||\lambda x - Tx|| + ||Tx||$ and $||\lambda x - Tx||=||Tx-\lambda x||$, we have that $||\lambda x|| - ||Tx|| \leq ||(T-\lambda I)x||$. Then since $||\lambda x = |\lambda|\cdot||x||$ and $-||Tx|| \geq -||T||\cdot||x||$, we have:

$$(|\lambda|-||T||)\cdot||x|| \leq ||(T-\lambda I)x|| \leq ||(T-\lambda I)||\cdot||x||$$

Assuming $x \neq 0$, we have $(|\lambda|-||T||) \leq ||(T-\lambda I)||$. I'm pretty sure that for an operator $S$, $||S^{-1}|| \geq \frac{1}{||S||}$.

If it is true that $(|\lambda|-||T||) \leq \frac{1}{||(T-\lambda I)^{-1}||} \leq ||(T-\lambda I)||$, then we have $||R_{\lambda}(T)||=||(T-\lambda I)^{-1}|| \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda|-||T||}$. Then, as $\lambda \to \infty$, the LHS goes to $0$.

Is the inequality $(|\lambda|-||T||) \leq \frac{1}{||(T-\lambda I)^{-1}||}$ okay and if so, why?

Comment: Note $\lVert (T-\lambda I)x\rVert \geqslant (\lvert\lambda\rvert - \lVert T\rVert)\lVert x\rVert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: How did the $\lambda$ and $T$ exchange places on the RHS?

Comment: @DanielFischer A bit dangerous, taking $\|x\|$ on the outside like that. And to ikievoyd: It's the triangle inequality: $\|\lambda x\|=\|(\lambda x-Tx)+Tx\|\le\|\lambda x-Tx\|+\|Tx\|$.

Comment: @inkievoyd $\|x\| = \|-x\|$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why is that dangerous?

Comment: @DanielFischer Never mind, it seemed to be done on the wrong side of the inequality, but on a second look it isn't, really. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm not sure how the inequality helps since we're talking about the inverse of $(T−\lambda I)$. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: A (positive) lower bound on $\lVert Sx\rVert$ [for all $x$] gives you an upper bound on $\lVert S^{-1} y\rVert$ [for all $y$].

Comment: Yes, $\lVert S^{-1}\rVert \geqslant \frac{1}{\lVert S\rVert}$ is correct. You have $$1 = \lVert I\rVert = \lVert S^{-1}\circ S\rVert \leqslant \lVert S^{-1}\rVert\cdot \lVert S\rVert.$$ And the inequalities hold for _all_ $x$, we can restrict our use to $x\neq 0$. For $x = 0$, they are trivial anyway, and give no information.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for all your help. So since $∥T−\lambda I∥ \geq (∣\lambda∣−∥T∥)$, as $\lambda \to \infty$, so does $||T- \lambda I||$. Then would $||(T-\lambda I)^{-1}||$ need to go towards $0$ in order to counteract $||T- \lambda I||$? Could we make that statement based on the fact that these are bounded operators?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not making the connections.

Comment: Can we get something similar for unbounded operators? But not the operator norm $||R_{\lambda}(T)||$ going to zero, but $||R_{\lambda}(T)x|| \to 0$ for some fixed $x \in X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\lvert\lambda\rvert > \lVert T\rVert$, we have a non-negative lower bound (strictly positive for $x\neq 0$) for $\lVert (T-\lambda I)x\rVert$, namely

$$\lVert (T-\lambda I)x\rVert \geqslant (\lvert\lambda\rvert - \lVert T\rVert)\lVert x\rVert.$$

Now set $x = (T-\lambda I)^{-1} y$ to obtain the inequality

$$\lVert y\rVert = \lVert(T-\lambda I)(T-\lambda I)^{-1}y\rVert \geqslant (\lvert\lambda\rvert -\lVert T\rVert)\lVert (T-\lambda I)^{-1}y\rVert$$

holdong for all $y\in X$. Dividing by $\lvert\lambda\rvert -\lVert T\rVert$ then yields

$$\lVert (T-\lambda I)^{-1} y\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert\lambda\rvert -\lVert T\rVert}\lVert y\rVert$$

for all $y\in X$, whence

$$\lVert (T-\lambda I)^{-1}\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert\lambda\rvert - \lVert T\rVert}\tag{$\ast$}$$

for all $\lambda$ with $\lvert\lambda\rvert > \lVert T\rVert$. It is clear from $(\ast)$ that $\lVert (T-\lambda I)^{-1}\rVert \to 0$ as $\lvert\lambda\rvert \to +\infty$.